# Extjs TreePanel not expanded

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I load a TreePanel with item expanded (defined in my json) but when it display it's not expanded.

Just the dir (icon) is open but the items are not display. And i load it use load store function to reload my treepanel.

[image]

```
storeTree = me.getTreePersonneStore();

            storeTree.load({
              params: {
                idPersonne: batch.proxy.getReader().jsonData.id, 
                lettrePersonne: batch.proxy.getReader().jsonData.lettre
              }
            })
```

My store :

```
    Ext.define('ModuleGestion.store.TreePersonne', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',

    requires: [
        'ModuleGestion.model.Personne'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'ModuleGestion.model.Personne',
            storeId: 'StoreTreePersonne',
            root: {
               expanded : true,
               text : 'Personnes',
               expandable : true,
               id : 'root',
               nodeType:'async',
               uiProvider:false
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                node: 'id',
                url: 'ModuleGestion/php/TreePersonne.php',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json'
                }
            },
            listeners: {
                beforeload: {
                    fn: me.beforeload,
                    scope: me
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    },

    beforeload: function(store, operation, eOpts) {
        operation.params.node = operation.node.get("id");
    }

});
```

My JSON:

```
[{
    id:"A",
    text:"A",
    expanded:true,
    children:[
    {
        id:"101",text:"AA AA",leaf:true},
        {id:"98",text:"AA AA",leaf:true},
        {id:"86",text:"AA AA",leaf:true},
        {id:"99",text:"AA AA",leaf:true},
        {id:"96",text:"AA AA",leaf:true},
        {id:"100",text:"AA AA",leaf:true},
        {id:"97",text:"AA AA",leaf:true}]
    }],
}]
```

My Tree:

```
{
    xtype: 'treepanel',
    id: 'TreePersonne',
    store: 'TreePersonne',
    viewConfig: {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following json. Children also have **expanded** property.

```
[{
    id:"A",
    text:"A",
    expanded:true,
    children:[
    {
        id:"101",text:"AA AA",leaf:true, expanded:true},
        {id:"98",text:"AA AA",leaf:true, expanded:true},
        {id:"86",text:"AA AA",leaf:true, expanded:true},
        {id:"99",text:"AA AA",leaf:true, expanded:true},
        {id:"96",text:"AA AA",leaf:true, expanded:true},
        {id:"100",text:"AA AA",leaf:true, expanded:true},
        {id:"97",text:"AA AA",leaf:true, expanded:true}]
    }],
}]
```

Alternatively, you can expand the children after panel loading too as:

```
YOUR_TREE_PANEL.expandChildren(true);
```